# How can I get string as input to Bigrams in nltk

Tags: python

I am new to nltk and I am using python. 
I am taking string as input to Bigrams. When I am showing the items of this. I am getting each character as a word.

```
import nltk   
string = "Batman Superman"   
bigram = nltk.bigrams(string) 
print bigram.item() 
[('B','a'),('a','t'),('t','m'),('m','a'),('a','n'),('n',' '),(' ','S'),
('S','u'),('u','p'),('p','e'),('e','r'),('r','m')('m','a'),('a','n')]
```

But I want output as [('Batman','Superman')]
please tell me how I get this output only taking string as input to
Bigrams function but not taking list as input.

Comment: You have to tokenize your string first. Refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347029/python-nltk-bigrams-trigrams-fourgrams)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so what is happening here is that the `bigrams` function is expecting a tokenized version of you corpus, that is a list of words in order.

When you pass it a string, `nltk` is doing its best and converts that string into a list of chars, and then produces the bigrams of that list, which happens to be pairs of chars.

If you want to get word-chunk bigrams, you will need to tokenize your input sentence like so:

```
>>> string = "Batman Superman"
>>> tokenized = string.split(" ")
>>> list(nltk.bigrams(tokenized))
[('Batman', 'Superman')]
```

Comment: But i want  [('Batman','Superman')] as output even though taking input as string.. Is this possible ??

Comment: No, because the `bigrams` function expects a list of tokens to work with. If you want it to be shorter, you could do `nltk.bigrams(string.split(" "))`.

Comment: A tokenized version of the string will represent the same data, just in the proper format for `nltk` to work with.

Comment: if i convert string into tokens and passes as input to bigrams function. then it will club the every possible pair of consecutive words(tokens). If i want to find the meaningful bigram how i will get meaningful bigram.

Comment: Please define "meaningful bigram." If you want to ask about semantic parsing, that should be a separate question.

Comment: No problem! If this answer has been helpful, please [upvote/accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)