# re.findall() is not returning all the Trigrams / ngrams in a sentence in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get a list of all the trigrams in a sentence which does not have  the starting of that sentence.

i wrote the following code :-

```
import re
s= "He was working on the table"
middle_trigram_list = re.findall("\s+[a-z]+\s[a-z]+\s[a-z]+\s+",s)
print (middle_trigram_list)
[' was working on ']
```

and i got the output only as [' was working on '] , i wonder why "working on the " was not included in the list.

Thanks!!

Comment: So you want overlapping results?

Comment: Consider using NLTK instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347029/python-nltk-bigrams-trigrams-fourgrams

Comment: Thanks!! That was exactly what i was looking for .